# What is the best name for a short composition (Suite, Sonata, Partita, etc.)?

Tags: composition, terminology

I have a short composition and I would like to give it a name but I don't know what term would be more appropriate (Suite, Sonata, Partita, another one?). The composition has a duration of 1:21, uses violins (melody and harmony) and most likely won't have other pieces as a continuation. What is the best name for that kind of short independent piece?

The tentative name would be "X in C Major", where X is the suitable term.

Comment: No piece with only one movement should be called either of these names. They're traditionally used for slightly different sequences of contrasting movements.

Comment: What form is your piece? Sonata, 32 bar song, ternary, variations, 12 bar blues, etc? Does it fit a common genre like waltz, tango, etc?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I really don't know. It just used 3 chords and recorded it. It seems baroque to me.

Answer (score 2):

Names of the type asked about depend wholly on the purpose, structure, or musical character of the piece, not its duration. Given that the piece is written for two violins, then the most appropriate title would be:

**Violin Duet in C Major**

Other options might be

- Melody in C Major for Two Violins
- Song in C Major for Two Violins
- Little Piece in C Major for Two Violins

Of the titles specifically mentioned,

- *Suite* designates a collection of pieces around a particular theme or purpose.
- *Sonata* is a specific musical structure involving a multipart composition in which the first movement (typically) is in sonata form.
- *Partita* is similar to a suite, but generally consists of dance-style music.

Comment: You're technically right, but it's also important to consider the structural aspect of a piece(often tied to the name), which may force it to be longer. Dance pieces like Waltzes and Polonaises are often in ABA song form, which allows them to be 2 or 3 minutes long. However, to properly develop a full-fledged sonata form, you need much more time. It's virtually impossible to create a good sonata form piece in two minutes. A rondo is virtually destined to be longer than a waltz(unless the sections of the waltz are abnormally long), due to their fundamental structural differences.

Comment: @OprenStein Did you intend to address your comment to the OP?

Comment: @OprenStein - What's a "good sonata form piece"? I've managed to create two sonata-form pieces that are less than 2 minutes long when with no repeats and have a recognizable exposition (complete with first and second theme groups), development, and recapitulation. This is inspired by the fact that I've heard multiple such **public-domain** examples, and there is at least one Beethoven sonata-form movement that is invariably barely over 2 minutes long but has no repeats (his Piano Sonata No. 30 in E Major, Op. 109, Mvmt. 2 "Prestissimo").

Comment: @Aaron If it's called "Melody in C Major...", ¿does it suggest that there is only melody and no harmony?

Comment: @AlfieGonzález Not necessarily. For example, Schumann wrote a piece titled "Melody", but it has harmony. See [Schumann Op. 68, No. 1](https://michaelkravchuk.com/free-piano-sheet-music-robert-schumann-op-68-no-1-melody/).

Answer (score 1):

A *Suite* is a baroque Form that is a collection of dances. So a Suite consists of multiple pieces. A *Partita* is a part of a Variation, but is also used in a Suite-like manner or even for any instrumental pieces. A *Sonata* originally implied a form and a structure, which has somewhat faded over time.

A modernist approach would be to not give a name at all and just call is a "piece in C major for ...". Quite common would be to simply designate the number of players (Duet, Trio, Quartet, Quintet, Sextet, Septet, Octet, ...). You can designate the form of the piece (Dance, Minuet, Variation, Melody, Chorale, ...). You can designate a form stolen from a different form of art (Literature: Proloque, Epiloque, ...). You can designate an implied meaning of the music (e.g. Liszt *La prédication aux oiseaux*). You can designate a term for the shortness of the music (Miniature, Bagatelle).

So in your case considering the music is short and has few instruments you could say *Miniature in C major for X violins*.

Answer (score 1):

Mentioning the key is only required if there is nothing else allowing distinction, I would not suggest it. (Except when writing for beginners, which are easily intimidated by accidentals.) There is an extra question concerning the key in titles [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/6688/2600).

Some choices:

- the piece has a title: "Sunny days" for 2 violins
- the piece has a classical structure: fugue for 2 violins
- if neither applies, there are classical terms without implications, like duet (see @Lazy; advantage is, that it is obviously fitting), improvisation, invention, impromptus.

Originally *sonata* was used for anything without voices (see Domenico Scarlatti) , presence of voices would have made a *cantata*, but since the *sonata form* appeared, the meaning got much more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Suite, as in Baroque suite, is a group of several dance forms usually unified by sharing the same key but differing in meter and tempo. Number of movements varies but allemande, courante, sarabande, gigue are the basic ones.

Sonata has a meaning which has changed over time, but the common use if for either sonata allegro form (formal sections of exposition, development, recapitulation) or a work that usually has at least one movement in that form.

Partita is basically the same thing as suite.

You can go on and on like this just listing descriptions, but if you didn't consciously write in a form or genre, why do you want to use terms like sonata, suite, etc. in the title? How would it be meaningful to apply one of those labels if you don't know what they mean? Sorry to be blunt, but to do that seems a bit pretentious.

You don't have to give form and key in your title. And if your work wasn't really meant as a formal example of something, I don't think it makes much sense to give it that sort of formal title.

In classical music many works were not really titled by the composers. The titles came later when published. And sometimes those titles were really plain, like *12 Waltzes* (with an opus number that was really a publishing number) and each waltz just 1, 2, 3...

Sometime works will fit a clear form, for example *ternary form*, but those works may get picturesque titles. Debussy wrote two books of piano preludes, most of which are in ternary form, but they all got evocative title like *The Girl with the Flaxen Hair*, or *The Sunken Cathedral*, etc.

Why not just title it by what it means to you? Or just do something like finish the sentence: "I wrote a...", and make that the title. In comments you said: *It just used 3 chords and recorded it. It seems baroque to me.*

Why not a title like this? *Impressions of the Baroque Using Three Chords*.

Comment: Ok. I see what you mean. The thing is that when I created it, it made me think of baroque, and the pieces that I remember the most of that style are Suites of Bach. But I cannot use that term because, according to the answers provided here, it makes no sense for an individual piece. Normally names are given by inspiration. How many Alexander are there in the world? But here the terms are specific to some criteria and I cannot just use one arbitrarily even if I like it.